# In reactjs, findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode error

Tags: reactjs

I am newbie in React.js and trying to use BackTop component in Ant Design library.
https://ant.design/components/back-top/

This component works fine.
But I found a error message in chrome browser console.

*index.js:1 Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of DomWrapper which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-find-node*

This is my code below.

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'; 
import './assets/scss/global.scss';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from './layouts/Header'; 
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About"; 
import { BackTop } from 'antd';

class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
        <Header/>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="content">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/about" component={About} /> 
            </Switch> 
          </div>
        </div> 
        <BackTop /> 
      </Router>
    )
  }
} 
export default App;
```

What do I need to change to fix the error ?

Comment: [`findDOMNode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#warning-about-deprecated-finddomnode-usage) has been deprecated. You should not use it. It seems like some library is still using `findDOMNode`. So, you should just ignore this as it will be fixed when the library authors update the code. See [this](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+findDOMNode)

Answer (score -1):

It's because of the library ant-design you are using. Some underlying dependencies of ant-design are using `findDOMNode`.

There is a big thread about this issue on their github: [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/22493)

It seems they're not planning to fix it soon.

As a workaround, I am adding this at the root file.
I'm suppressing the warning like so:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
const consoleError = console.error.bind(console);
// eslint-disable-next-line
console.error = (errObj, ...args) => {
  if (
    (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && typeof errObj.message === 'string' && args.includes('findDOMNode')
  ) {
    return;
  }
  consoleError(errObj, ...args);
};
```

I know this is not a fix, but at least my console is not bloated with `findDOMNode` messages. Until And-Design fixes this, this will do.